# select value from table != value in array

Tags: php, arrays, html-select

array from 1 to 10
i want to make a drop down to select values that in array excludeing values in the table in the database
ex:id=3 is in the table ==>drop down choices(1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
ex:id=4 is in the table ==>drop down choices(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10)

```
<select name="Alert_Severtiy_No" class="form-control">
<option value="">select</option>
 $no=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

foreach($no as $key):
  $hh="select * from Alert_Severtiy where Alert_Severtiy_No Not <>$no";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connect, $hh);

echo '<option value="'.$hh.'">'.$hh.'</option>'; 
endforeach;
echo'

</select>
```

Comment: Could you fix the visibility of your code?

Comment: Hi! please try to fix the formatting of your code and at least try and ask something that remotely resembles a question so we can help you out!

Answer (score 2):

In your query you need to use $key instead of $no

```
$hh="select * from Alert_Severtiy where Alert_Severtiy_No Not <>$key";
```

But I would suggest you get all your results from the database at once, and not query the database each time running through the loop.

You could do something like below:

```
$here = implode(",", $no);
$hh="select * from Alert_Severtiy where Alert_Severtiy_No Not IN ($here)";
```

Then loop through the results returned.